# beginner/learner implementation of foreach in haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I am trying to implement a foreach morphism so as to test my understanding of morphism definition and pattern-matching... Obviously I miss both points completely.

Could you correct me ? I want the morphism `foreach` to takes a list of `a` and a morphism `f` as arguments and to return the list of all the results `r` of `f` applied to all `a` elements.

```
foreach :: [a] → f → [r]
foreach [] f = []
foreach x:[] f = (f x):[]
foreach []:x f = []:(f x)
foreach (x:xs) f = (f x) : (foreach (xs f))
```

When compiled, I have `src\Main.hs:23:0: Parse error in pattern`

Comment: By the way: This already exists, is called `map` and defined in half the lines.

Comment: @delnan: with arguments this way, this is called `for` (and defined in terms of `map` probably).

Comment: @Alexandre: Ah yes, overlooked argument order... definition would be `flip map`.

Comment: The third and fourth lines are unnecessary. The third is taken care of by the second and fifth lines, while the fourth simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Dan thx for the noticing these incoherences.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is syntactic, in this line:

```
foreach x:[] f = (f x):[]
```

Constructor application in patterns usually need to be parenthesized. This would work:

```
foreach (x:[]) f = (f x):[]
```

Incidentally... function application is highest precedence, so on the other hand you don't need parentheses on the right-hand side:

```
foreach (x:[]) f = f x:[]
```

The above holds for any infix constructor, but as a final note, for lists in particular there is a special syntax:

```
foreach [x] f = [f x]
```

There are other issues with your code as it stands, but that's the immediate error. A quick overview of the other problems:

```
foreach :: [a] → f → [r]
```

Type variables are implicitly universally quantified, so this means *any* type `f`. You need a more specific type, namely `a -> r`.

```
foreach x:[] f = (f x):[]
```

This is unnecessary--the recursive case will work correctly here, applying `f` to `x` and calling itself on the tail, giving the empty list case.

```
foreach []:x f = []:(f x)
```

I don't think this means what you think it means--this is pattern matching the head of a list against the empty list `[]`, implying that the function is working on a list of lists.

```
foreach (x:xs) f = (f x) : (foreach (xs f))
```

The parentheses here are either unnecessary or incorrect. Again, function application has higher precedence than operators like `:`. Additionally, `(xs f)` means applying `xs` to `f`, as if it were a function. To apply `foreach` to two arguments, simply `foreach xs f` will suffice.

---

For comparison, here's the source code for the (identical except for argument order) standard library function `map`:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map _ []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

Comment: thx for all precisions, namely function application with higher precedence.

Comment: and great example with the implementation of map

Answer (score 3):

The type signature you give, is (at least in the Haskell compiler's opinion) bogus.  It's a function which takes a list of items of any `a` and a value of *any* type `f`, and produces a list of values of *any* type `r`.  It's like saying "I have a bunch of elephants and a screwdriver.  Turn each elephant into a mango".

It seems your goal is to implement the `map` function:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Of course, it's perfectly valid to flip the arguments:

```
foreach :: [a] -> (a -> b) -> [b]
```

Your implementation is pretty close, but there are a few issues.

The biggest thing is to bear in mind that you're working with *lists*, not *arrays*.  The `:` operator, also known as "cons", takes an item and prepends it to a list (e.g. `1 : [2,3,4]`).  You can't use it to arbitrarily concatenate items and lists, as you do in `[]:(f x)`.  There is the `++` operator which concatenates two lists (e.g. `[f x] ++ xs`, which is the same as `(f x) : xs`), but you shouldn't need it to implement `foreach`.

Lastly, `(foreach (xs f))` doesn't do what you may think it does.  It is not like `foreach(xs,f)` in a C-style language, it is like `foreach(xs(f))`.  `(xs f)`, by itself, is like using `xs` as a function and applying `f` as the argument.  Instead, you want `(foreach xs f)`.

I will stop here, to avoid giving away too much.  One little tidbit though: function application has higher precedence than any operator, so instead of `(f x) : (foreach xs f)`, you can say `f x : foreach xs f`.

Comment: nice to know it already exist as map. I have used it in tutorial but i forgot it ;-), I'll use it now. I have also notice the existence of the keyword forall as a Leksah auto-completion proposition, but I couldn't find its syntax.

Comment: @Stephane Rolland: `forall a b. (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`.  You'll need to an enable a Haskell language extension to use this syntax.  See [Existentially quantified types](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types).

Answer (score 2):

You've forgot to put `()` in `foreach []:x f = []:(f x)` and incorrectly specified the function type, the following should now compile:

```
foreach :: [a] -> (a -> r) -> [r]
foreach [] f = []
foreach (x:[]) f = (f x):[]
foreach (x:xs) f = (f x) : (foreach xs f)
```

and run:

```
*Main> foreach [1..20] (+1)
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]
```

Comment: `(a -> r)` here means that the second argument to `foreach` is the function which converts type `a` to type `r`. If you would for example specified function type as `foreach :: [a] -> (a -> a) -> [a]`, you'd be unable to evaluate `foreach [1..20] show`, because `show` produces a `String`, and your function takes value of one type and returns the value of the same type.

Comment: :-O You're welcome @Stephane Questions tagged "haskell" are far more active than "scheme", "racket" or "erlang" are. I think I need to hang out here a bit.

Comment: The third line is not necessary by the way (`(x:xs)` matches `(x:[])`, binds `xs` to `[]` and then terminates on the next recursion) instead.

Comment: @delnan: Indeed, I just focused my attention on syntax and function type definition which prevented the source from compiling.

Comment: @Yasir, I move the answer status to camcann's answers because he also deals about the incoherences of writing `foreach [] f = []` and `foreach (x:[]) f = (f x):[]` but if I could check two answers as correct answers I would let yours, that was first, and remains over all rather correct.

Answer (score 2):

Just a small addendum. Aside from recursive pattern matching, one can also implement `foreach` in a clean way by using list comprehension:

```
foreach aList f = [ f a | a <- aList ]
```

That's it.